# Как создать горизонтальный список из div или ul

Tags: html, css

Нужно создать список из трех колонок в ширину и много (неизвестно вниз).
Формат

## 1 | 2 | 3

## 4 | 5 | 6

и тд.
Попробовал так:

```css
.ul_main ul {display:block; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.ul_main li{display:inline-block;width:32.20338983%; background: #f2f2f2; height: 150px; margin-top: 10px; padding: 3px;}
```

Но как только в списке строка не помещается и переходит на другую, все сразу смещается.
Как исправить или может быть посоветуете деление из дивов как то сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте css masonry

Comment: Гугл не катит? Найдите любой фреймверк css и посмотрите как там реализовано.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов решения данной задачи.

**Пример 1** `display: inline-block;`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100px;  
  line-height: 100px;
  color:#000;  
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

ul>li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  <li><span>7</span></li>
  <li><span>8</span></li>
  <li><span>9</span></li>
  <li><span>10</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Пример 2** `float:left;`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul>li {
  float:left;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100px;  
  line-height: 100px;
  color:#000;  
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

ul>li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  <li><span>7</span></li>
  <li><span>8</span></li>
  <li><span>9</span></li>
  <li><span>10</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Пример 3** `dispaly: flex`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

ul>li {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100px;  
  line-height: 100px;
  color:#000;  
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

ul>li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  <li><span>7</span></li>
  <li><span>8</span></li>
  <li><span>9</span></li>
  <li><span>10</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Пример 4** для блоков с разной высотой [masonry grid](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html):

```js
$('ul').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: 'li',
  columnWidth: 'li',
  percentPosition: true
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul>li {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100px;  
  line-height: 100px;
  color:#000;  
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

ul>li:nth-of-type(2n){
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;;
}

ul>li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>  

  <ul>
    <li><span>1</span></li>
    <li><span>2</span></li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
    <li><span>4</span></li>
    <li><span>5</span></li>
    <li><span>6</span></li>
    <li><span>7</span></li>
    <li><span>8</span></li>
    <li><span>9</span></li>
    <li><span>10</span></li>
  </ul>
```

**Еще один вариант с flex для блоков разной высоты:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

ul>li {
  width: 33.333%;
  color:#000;  
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

ul>li>div {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .25rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 80px;
}

ul>li span {
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><div><span>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, suscipit!</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque soluta vel, ullam voluptatem nemo in beatae, dolor ea doloremque aliquid!</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi sint id rerum, sequi omnis! In assumenda, iusto officiis ad nisi aliquid, mollitia odio voluptatibus praesentium saepe eveniet, rerum optio dicta.</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, ullam.</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>8 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet doloribus sequi velit reprehenderit placeat eaque.</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>9 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquam, quis iure ut tenetur explicabo, est asperiores pariatur placeat hic.</span></div></li>
    <li><div><span>10 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Во всех вариантах кроме последнего (он не подходит) есть одна проблема: что если строка длинная она съезжает. Мне нужно чтобы она умещалась в рамках заданного блока (есть ul>li { width: 33.333%; height: 100px; } - этого мне хватает чтобы уместить текст который переходит на другую строку. Вот пример https://carfix.ru/uslugi/diagnostika как хотелось бы сделать только текст длиннее и хотелось бы перенести его на вторую строку в рамках длины и высоты.

Comment: @ПетровКирилл, длинная строка? `ul`? Добавила еще вариант для блоков `li` разной высоты

Comment: <li> либо в теге <span>

Comment: Последний самое то. Спасибо. Еще вопрос остался как по вертикали отцентрировать текст в блоке...

Comment: Вот так все одинаковые получил ul>li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
   min-height: 80px; /* Минимальная высота */ 
  padding: .25rem;
}

Comment: @ПетровКирилл, обновила с выравниванием

Comment: Отлично, то, что нужно. Огромное Спасибо.